# Will benzyl halides undergo SN1 or SN2 mechanism in a polar aprotic solvent?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, nucleophilic-substitution, halogenation

If benzyl bromide reacts with KF in the presence of a polar aprotic solvent like DMF, will it undergo SN1 mechanism or SN2 mechanism ?

I understand that polar aprotic solvents favour SN2 mechanism but i came across a paragraph in my textbook which said that benzyl and allyl halides show high reactivity towards SN1 reaction (due to the stability of the carbocation formed) however, they failed to mention if it would take place in polar protic or polar aprotic solvents or both.

If it follows SN1, will it be more likely for the nucleophile to get attached to the benzene ring itself as compared to the side chain ?

Comment: Probably a mix of both processes but this will never result in nucleophile attack on the aromatic ring.

Comment: Why wouldn't it attack the ring ? The canonical structure in which the positive charge is delocalised in the ortho and para positions of the ring would be a secondary carbocation, which should be more stable than a side chain carbocation right ? @Waylander

Comment: It never occurs. Attack is always at the benzylic site. This demonstrates that the model of canonical structures is limited in its usefulness.